# $.ajax post loads html code from current page instead of requested php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im new to javascript, but have to use it for an ajax load of a .php

This is my ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "neo4j.php",
    data: {"url": url, "userAgent": uA}
});
alert(url);
```

});

It should post the datas to neo4j.php.

My Start.php looks like

```
<head><title>Start</title></head>
<?php
include("db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM category_paths LIMIT 10";
$pattern = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($pattern)){
  if ($row->descendant_id == 1) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/2play/Start.php'>$row->descendant_id</a><br>";
  }else {   
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/2play/Section.php/?sec=$row->descendant_id'>$row->descendant_id</a><br>";
  }
}
?>
<footer><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script></footer>
```

Here my code works.

But if I click on a link to section.php

```
<head><title>Section</title></head>
<?php
include("db.php");

echo "<a href='http://localhost/2play/Start.php'>1</a><br>";

if(isset($_GET["sec"])) {
  $sec = $_GET["sec"];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM category_paths WHERE ancestor_id = $sec AND length = 1";
$pattern = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($pattern)){
  echo "<a href='http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=$row->descendant_id'>$row->descendant_id</a><br>";
}
?>
<div id="js">test</div>
<footer><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</footer>
```

My ajax.js dont load the js code, instead it load the html-code of the current page. Copy from loaded section.php with firebug:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Section</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Start.php">1</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=123">123</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=124">124</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=125">125</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=156">156</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost/2play/Game.php/?game=197">197</a>
<br>
<footer>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript">

<--Here the script should be loaded, but it relaods the raw non-php code from section.php-->
  <head><title>Section</title></head>
  <a href='http://localhost/2play/Start.php'>1</a><br>
  <footer><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
  </footer>
<--End-->

</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

What I already found out:
If I manually add some get-vars to the Start.php url like

```
http://localhost/Start.php?foo=bar
```

the script wont work and do some failure as above.

**SOLVED**
Ok I found my mistake, and cant believe it.
It is because i had an slash in the link before I set the get-vars http://localhost/2play/Section.php**/**?sec=$row->descendant_id'> . After deleting it, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Open Developer's console.

Comment: `data1 = "foo"; data2 = "bar";` are not valid parameters for `$.ajax` and are syntax errors.

Comment: Corrected the code above, this writting error was jsut here and not in my code.

Dev-Console says Syntax error in line 1 which is caused by 
    "<head><title>Section</title></head>"

Comment: Post your actual js code. There's no way that what you posted is your real code if an entire page is loaded when you click on a link.

Comment: Added mysql-code. But my job isnt to create the page this is just a test-page to test if my code works. My part was to prog the neo4j.php and now to include it per ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake, and cant believe it. It is because i had a slash in the link before I set the get-vars

```
http://localhost/2play/Section.php**/**?sec=$row->descendant_id'>
```

After deleting it, the problems disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should nod declare variable inside `$.ajax`. Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data1 = "foo",
        data2 = "bar";
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "foobar.php",
        data: {"data1": data1, "data2": data2}
    });
    alert(data1);
});
```

More about AJAX can follow the [**link**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: ok, this was just a writing error here, in my code its correct. Fixed the post, but not hte problem.